# Motorola MC32N0 can't find rfidapi32.dll

Tags: windows-ce, motorola, windows-mobile-6

When I run my application I get the above error in the error log.
I have copied the

> symbol.RFID3.Device.dll

to the windows folder and to the folder where I start my EXE file. I am stuck in this project .Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever find a solution. This problem is posted all over the web with no solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this DLL (that looks like a .NET assembly) is not just a wrapper from another (native) DLL?
This is the impression I got from you other post.
And adding details to the original post would be better than opening a new thread.